# English translation of Preisach's paper "Über die magnetische Nachwirkung"

Tags: electromagnetism, specific-reference, ferromagnetism

This paper [1] has been already cited 2000+ times according to the statistics of Google Scholar. Hence I assume there should be English translated version for such a classic paper on hysteresis but I could not find it.

[1] Preisach, Ferenc. "Über die magnetische Nachwirkung." Zeitschrift für physik 94, no. 5-6 (1935): 277-302.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the [link](https://dx.doi.org/10.1109/TMAG.2016.2548379). It's open access.

Comment: Permalink: https://dx.doi.org/10.1109/TMAG.2016.2548379